# Parse String into Comparator Type in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, comparison, comparator

Given the Strings

```
String str1 = "==";
String str2 = "<=";
String str3 = "!=";
...
```

Is there a way to parse those Strings into their corresponding comparator types to use them directly in a comparison (like "comparator.parseComparator(str1)")? Or do i need to find a different way?

Comment: Use `switch`, or you can convert all to String(ex: a == b) then use some engine to parse and get result :)

Comment: @RongNguyen no, `switch` is not a good option in this case. `map` is far more better

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Your solution is cool, upvoted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `map<String, Comparator>`

where the key is the operator you want to apply, and the object is the relevant `Comparator` instance.

Get the relevant comparator by key and apply it whenever you want.

Comment: What would the relevant Comparator instance look like? Moreover my comparable values are of different data types (string, int, float) and will have different names.

Comment: If you need to compare different types of values, you need to determine how do you compare these values of different types to each other. How do you compare string and double? You convert string to double and compare two doubles, or you convert double to string and compare two strings?

Comment: I will always compare values of the same type (int with int, String with String), but the comparator needs to process every data type to be used universally. Just like you could use "<=" with "int1 <= int2" as well as with "float1 <= float2".

Comment: In this case do not use standard java `Comparator` interface. Write your own `CustomComparator` interface and declare methods `compare(int, int)`, `compare(float, float)`, `compare(double, double)`, `compare(String, String)` and so on. Then make implementations of this interface for every operation. And use map as I advised in my answer to get a relevant custom comparator by operation string.